# how to interrupt Terminal command after vim | grep combination

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

Sometimes I do `less file` with `grep` to find some strings.

But sometimes by mistake I write `vim` instead of `less`:

```
vim file | grep
```

Then Terminal will be "blocked". Like this:

```
$ vim ~/Documents/http.txt  | grep -A2 facebook
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

`Ctrl + c` does not interrupt the command. Console becomes unusable. I can only close `Console`. I tried the same in guake terminal and standard xubuntu terminal.

Where is a way to revive current Console after `vim | grep`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can suspend the command and kill the process.

To suspend, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>.

@Ravenix's answer explains how to find `pid` and kill that process.

Comment: Yes, it helps. `ctrl + z` && kill process.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because vim outputs continuous data that gets piped into grep.

you can in another tab do `ps -aux | grep vim` which will return all processes containing vim:

```
username  31239  0.2  0.2  61212  8324 pts/13   S+   14:07   0:00 vim
```

then you can kill this proces with the command kill process-id: `kill 31239` which kills the proces and unfreeze this tab.